# Cummulative sum with a python list

Tags: python, list

I have to make myself a recursive function : `cumulative_sum(hist,initial_sum)`, I'll explain myself with an example it will be more comprehensive:

`hist=[0,1,2,3,4]`, `initial=0`
`cumulative_sum` need to return `[0+0(the first is initial sum),0+0+1,0+0+1+2,0+0+1+2+3,0+0+1+2+3+4]`=`[0,1,3,6,10]`

second exemple:
hist=[2,4,5,3], initial_sum=7
return [2+7,2+7+4,2+7+4+5,2+7+4+5+3]

i can't change the parameters of cumulative_sum and can't change the list hist

i tried this but my prog did'nt return anything:

```
def cumulative_sum(hist, initial_sum=0):
    if len(hist)==0:
        new=[]
        return new.append(hist[0]+initial_sum)
    return cumulative_sum(hist[1:],new[-1])
```

this second prog was doing th job but my teacher tell me that i can't use a global variable (new)

new = []

```
def cumulative_sum(hist, initial_sum=0):
    if len(hist) == 0:
        return new
    new.append(hist[0] + initial_sum)

    return cumulative_sum(hist[1:], new[-1])
```

thanks for your help if you got some idea i'm here!!

Comment: If you can use itertools use : ```list(itertools.accumulate(data))```

Comment: @SreeramTP He wants an `initial_sum`  thing too

Comment: @U11-Forward `itertools.accumulate` has an `initial` keyword, although it works a little differently.  It leads off with the value and the result is one element longer.  `itertools.accumulate(hist[1:],initial=hist[0])` would work.

Comment: ok thanks I'll check i don't know this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
def cumulative_sum(hist, initial_sum=0):
    if len(hist): # length non-zero
        total = initial_sum + hist[0] # compute first value
        return [total] + cumulative_sum(hist[1:],total) # append result of remaining values
    else: # length is zero
        return []

print(cumulative_sum([0,1,2,3]))
print(cumulative_sum([2,3,5,4],7))
```

```
[0, 1, 3, 6]
[9, 12, 17, 21]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try a `for` loop:

```
hist = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
cumulative_sum = []
c = 0
for i in hist:
    c += i
    cumulative_sum.append(c)
print(cumulative_sum)
```

Or try a list comprehension as follows:

```
print([sum(hist[:i + 1])for i in range(len(hist))])
```

Both codes output:

```
[0, 1, 3, 6, 10]
```

**Edited:**

As the OP mentioned he doesn't want a `for` loop, so try this function:

```
def cumulative_sum(hist, initial_sum):
    if hist:
        return [hist[0] + initial_sum] + cumulative_sum(hist[1:], hist[0] + initial_sum)
    else:
        return []
    
print(cumulative_sum([2, 3, 5, 4], 7))
```

Output:

```
[9, 12, 17, 21]
```

Comment: @DoronSachaSlomovits Please check my second example, I use a list comprehension

Comment: @DoronSachaSlomovits Please accept if my code helps you :-)

Comment: @DoronSachaSlomovits Please check my edited part, it should work now

Comment: sorry but we cannot use the word for or while i think they got a program witch check if there is the words for or while...

Comment: @DoronSachaSlomovits Check out my answer now